# Rails where fields concatenated like search query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm attempting to create a search method on one of my Active Record models.

I want users to be able to search for a record in the database.

I know I can do something like this: `Model.where('field like ?', "%#{query}%')`

But it's not just one field, it's two fields (first name and last name).  But I don't want to search them separately, I want to concatenate first name and last name and search where the concatenated field is like the search query.

Can this be done with Active Record similar to how SQL fields can be concatenated?  What's the best solution?

Comment: I guess the best solution is to do: `Model.where('first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")`. If you don't like like this use MySQL's full text search capabilities: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class method in your model as shown:

```
def self.search_by_full_name(query)
  where("CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
end
```

But in Rails, it is more common to declare a scope rather than a class method in such scenarios, like this:

```
scope :search_by_full_name ->(query) { where("CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{query}%") }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same [where](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) method with different fields. For example

```
Model.where(first_name: "Jonathan", last_name: "Smith")
```

That will give you all the **relations** (in Rails 4) where first_name **AND** last_name match.

If you want a query more dynamic (for example if you want to use both: `OR`, `AND`), you can use [find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class) this:

```
Person.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM people WHERE first_name = ? OR first_name = ? AND last_name = ?", first_name1, first_name2, last_name)
```

But it might require more specific code-chemistry for constructing such a SQL query-string